# Where to ask for advice about how to store data for an application

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking to build a video chatroom app where users can create / join private chat rooms, and I would appreciate some advice on how to go about storing the chat data. Whenever a new user joins the room, they should receive a history of all the previous chat messages, as well as the list of current users in the room.

On average, I expect chat rooms to be destroyed (ie. everyone has left the room) within a few hours of their creation. Thus, most of the data that needs to be stored is very temporary. On the other hand, messages in the chat will probably be somewhat frequent, and the data will be updated often.

Where should I go to ask for recommendations on how to store this data? It doesn't sound like this fits on Stack Overflow. Software Engineering or Databases seem like better options, though I don't necessarily want to restrict my options to databases only (maybe there are solutions that don't require a database, for example storing the data on the client side).

Comment: You should try at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just posted there and it was deleted almost instantly :(

Comment: @shmth: Did you include the result of your extensive research in the question? [Stefan Mischook](https://www.youtube.com/user/killerphp/videos) now has live streams daily where he answers such very broad questions (e.g. "Should I use [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) or [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony)"?)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ JFYI [question asked at SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/409225/31260 "removed by a moderator") was blatantly off-topic over there ([recommendation kind](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - "...I would prefer to use NoSQL in this case, what would be some good options?")